# Python Spyder reset

Tags: python, spyder

I was using python(x,y), which came with Spyder. Yesterday, Spyder crashed I can't figure it out how to fix it. I uninstalled python(x,y) and reinstalled, still the same problem.

If I try to open Spyder I get this message:

```
Spyder crashed during last session

If Spyder does not start at all and before submitting a bug report, please try to reset setting to defaults by running Spyder with the command line option '--reset:

python spyder --reset
```

Of course, I tried to do the above, but it doesn't seem like I have Spyder in my path. When I try to put

```
python spyder --reset
```

in my command prompt window, I get this error message:

```
python: can't open file 'spyder': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I made some attempts of trying to add spyder to path, but they all failed. How should I go about adding Spyder to path?

I am using Windows Vista on a 32 bit system.

My Spyder Crash report looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 1547, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 1472, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 555, in setup
    multithreaded=self.multithreaded)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\console.py", line 54, in __init__
    light_background=light_background)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\internalshell.py", line 101, in __init__
    debug, profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\shell.py", line 698, in __init__
    ShellBaseWidget.__init__(self, parent, history_filename, debug, profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\shell.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.history = self.load_history()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\shell.py", line 500, in load_history
    if rawhistory[1] != self.INITHISTORY[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am terrible with this stuff, so I might be missing something completely obvious or doing something really stupid.

I am wondering if anyone else ran into a similar problem, or can just give suggestions on what to do, and how to do this "reset" thing, or maybe other advice.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: try: `python  -c "from spyderlib.spyder import main; main()" --reset`

Comment: Your code worked to reset Spyder, and that fixed the problem. Everything works now. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: One more comment for Anaconda users.  My Spyder was working fine until I had a windows crash. I tried various things I found on the net but nothing worked.  Then, when trying to install PyScripter as a desperate alternative, I found a directory in my Users\myname folder called ".spyder2" and inside that folder there is a folder called "spyder.lock".  I simply deleted the spyder.lock folder and everything was able to run as it did pre-crash.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @user1269942 Actually when resetting Spyder, the folder "spyder.lock" is removed, in addition to other folders in ".spyder".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`python` doesn't search `spyder` in the `PATH` e.g.:

```
c:\some\dir> python some_file
```

Here `python` tries to read `c:\some\dir\some_file` file i.e., it looks in the current directory for `some_file` file.

```
c:\some\dir> python another_dir\some_file
```

Here `python` tries to read `c:\some\dir\another_dir\some_file` file i.e., it looks in the `another_dir` directory for `some_file` file.

```
c:\some\dir> python C:\path\to\some_file
```

Here `python` tries to read `C:\path\to\some_file` file i.e., it looks in the `C:\path\to` directory.

---

If documentation says run: `python spyder --reset` it assumes that you're in the directory where `spyder` script lives. It works both from the source checkout `scripts` directory (if you'd like to run it without installation) and from whatever directory the installation puts scripts in.

Installation process should create `spyder` or `spyder.bat` files. If `spyder.bat` in your `PATH` then you could run it as:

```
c:\any\dir> spyder
```

So instead of `python spyder --reset` you could try:

```
c:\any\dir> spyder --reset
```

---

The traceback shows that the first executed function is `spyderlib.spyder.main()`, 
[source code for the `spyder` script](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/source/browse/scripts/spyder) confirms it, so you can run:

```
python -c "from spyderlib.spyder import main; main()" --reset
```

Comment: It solved the same problem I just had (thanks). BTW: Resetting of course deletes your personal settings wrt spyder. You may prior to the reset look at your `.spyder` directory (somewhere near home folder) to try to save some of the settings for after the reset.

Answer (score 15):

don't worry, it is very easy to reset the spyder. for windows 10 users, you all need to type 'spyder' in 'Cortana' then you can see in apps category something like 'reset spyder setting' just click on that and some black screen will open and your problem will be solved. now you can open your spyder.

Comment: Hey@Hiten welcome to stack-overflow give answer on the new post you are giving on the  old post please avoid this and this post already accepted answers.

Comment: @Hiten, thanks for this answer, it solved my problem straight away!

Comment: @Hiten thank you for posting. I was trying all above-mentioned things and that was not working for me at all. I saw your answer and yup it worked. Thank you again

Answer (score 6):

I have this problem in windows and it resolved by updating the spyder

```
pip install -U spyder
```

Comment: in Anaconda, use: conda install -c anaconda spyder

Answer (score 5):

I am working with conda virtual environments and if you run 
`python spyder --reset it` it will output the same error message. However, unlike stated above, no need to uninstall anaconda or look for any files.

Just activate your virtual environment as you usually do and write (no need for 'python' in there):

```
conda activate [name of your virtual env]
spyder --reset
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the users' spyder settings are in the user folder .Spyder file name.By deleting it.You will be able to restart the IDE and a new .Spyder directory would be created

Answer (score 3):

Best solution as per my experience: uninstall spyder first, delete all the spyder files under `conda > lib > site-packages > ..`

```
1. pip install ipython

2. pip install spyder

3. spyder --reset
```

Comment: This solution worked perfect for me. Other options mentioned above did not work.

Answer (score 1):

For starters in winpython, I too faced this problem of spyder/spyder-reset not starting . And finally this is how it started :

opened command line went to :

`D:\manas\mak\crap\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\scripts`

typed in `spyder.bat`

And that opened spyder .

Perhaps the environment variable is stuck at .exe when clicking on the spyder icon and preventing it to load.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had both two installations of Python27---the Ananaconda distribution and the other. Python27 folders appeared before the Anaconda ones in my search path, although Spyder was executed through the Anaconda executable.

It turned out that making the Anaconda distribution folders first in the PYTHONPATH solved the problem.

An easier solution--avoid multiple installations of Python27 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method about "python -c "from spyderlib.spyder import main; main()" --reset",but it seems that I don't have the spyderlib.spyder.Then,I solve this problem through install another version of spyder(you can find from anaconda if you use it),you can run:

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder-app=2.3.8
```

and it works.

Comment: this will downgrade all of anaconda and not just spyder

Comment: it may downgrade dependencies, but shouldn't downgrade the rest of anaconda, unless there's a bug...

Answer (score -1):

Searched for spyder.bat, per prev answer, and after changing to that directoy - ran the python spyder --reset command.

```
C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.3.3\python-2.7.3>cd scripts
C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.3.3\python-2.7.3\Scripts>python spyder --reset
```