# UnicodeDecodeError on Spyder startup

Tags: python, utf-8, anaconda, spyder, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958189/spyder-unicode-decode-error-in-startup). When trying to start Spyder from terminal or Anaconda navigator, I get the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 7, in <module>
    from spyder.app.start import main
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 35, in <module>
    from spyder.config.manager import CONF
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/config/manager.py", line 351, in <module>
    CONF = ConfigurationManager()
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/config/manager.py", line 64, in __init__
    self._user_config = MultiUserConfig(
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/config/user.py", line 782, in __init__
    self._configs_map[name] = config_class(**new_kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/config/user.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._load_from_ini(previous_fpath)
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/config/user.py", line 333, in _load_from_ini
    self.read(fpath, encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1017, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The proposed solution doesn't work for me, as I struggle to find the right file to replace `encoding='utf-8' with encoding='latin-1'`. The file `userconfig.py` is not present in my anaconda installation folder. Looking with

```
grep -rn 'self.read(self.filename(), encoding='
```

results in the path
`pkgs/anaconda-navigator-1.9.12-py38_0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py:279`.
But changing that line accordingly doesn't make any difference.

The same problem occurs if I try to run

```
spyder --reset
```

My setup: Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.8.3, Spyder 4.1.4, Qt: 5.9.7, PyQt: 5.9.2

What I tried so far:

- reinstalled anaconda
- reinstalled python (2.7, 3.6, 3.8.3)
- tried with various versions of spyder (3.2.3 - 4.1.4)
- checked if charmap is set to 'utf-8' (it is)
- installed Spyder with miniconda (same result)
- made sure my username doesn't contain any non-ascii characters

I managed to make Spyder start when using an environment with python 2.7 and Spyder versions below 4.0, but i need the newer versions of both python and Spyder for my projects.

I am really stuck here and appreciate any of your advice!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I'm very sorry to hear that you're having this terrible issue with Spyder. To try to fix it, please run this command in a terminal: `rm -r ~/.config/spyder-py3`. That should be enough to allow you start Spyder again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you so much, totally solved my problem! I am finally able to start spyder again :)

Comment: Very glad to know that! We'll try to improve the way we reset our settings, so it's possible to get same results by simply running `spyder --reset` in the future.