# How to completely remove package from Python environment?

Tags: python-3.x

I uninstalled Spyder using "pip uninstall spyder" inside a Python environment where it was installed, and then removed all folders in site-packages that had Spyder in its name, and rebooted the system. After reinstalling Spyder again, all the previous files were still available in the tab menu. My question is, how do I completely remove a package so there is no trace left of it. In order to do a clean installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Spyder reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747158/python-spyder-reset)

Comment: presumably https://stackoverflow.com/a/38849624/7941251